# UK visitors visa refused because no proof of ties

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, serial-refusals, proof-of-ties

I applied for a visit visa for my mother to visit us in the UK from Pakistan. This is the 3rd time in 2 years that the visa has been refused citing the same reason that she will not return to Pakistan after her visa expires. We used all kind of documents to prove that she will go back but unfortunately they didn't satisfy UK immigration department.

Could Somone advise us on what are we missing or if we should make future applications?

[image][image]

Comment: @shoaib sardar The financial information is contradictory (no income or savings stated in the application, but bank statements showing pension income and a deposit from an unknown source), and they think your mother has no clear ties to Pakistan so nothing that would discourage her from overstaying in the UK rather than compel her to return to Pakistan. You need to stop applying unless circumstances change significantly.

Comment: Forget it. She’s not coming anytime soon.

Comment: Contrary to what most people are going to say here about it, it does not look that bad. I can almost feel like its a borderline rejection and this visa could have been approved had you made a little more effort to demonstrate her ties to your Home country. You were really close. Read the TSE archives linked here and prepare a better application that addresses the concerns they raised.

Comment: hi, thanks mate for reply, first 2 time i did use her land and house document as she owned them but still they give us same reason and somebody told us do not use too much document thats why we didnt add this time about property.Really so stress dont know what document we should use to satisfied them she will go back, she got whole family in Pakistan( mom/dad/sis/bro etc) i am a only person and my mrs here so why she gonna stay here and leave whole her family there.i am also ready to put my house document or any money for security if they want but im not sure immigration will approve that.

Comment: @Shoaib Sardar Try getting an Immigration Adviser to check the application and supporting documents next time https://www.gov.uk/find-an-immigration-adviser For example https://www.lawfirmuk.net/visitorvisas